# I want to see build history view include the second in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins version 2.60.3
I can't see build detail time(include second)
What should I do?

[image: Jenkins image]

Answer (score 1):

### I found workaround:

1. install '[Jenkins secondary timestamper plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/secondary-timestamper-plugin)' v1.1
2. Job Configure -> After Build -> Set second timestamp as description -> Save

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM8DI.png]